# Which one is verb?

Tags: verbs

> Deep into distant woodlands winds a mazy way, reaching to overlapping spurs of mountains bathed in their hill-side blue.

An excerpt from Moby Dick, and I don't know what is a verb in this sentence.

Comment: There were many mistakes in the quote you gave us. Please be sure to copy quotes verbatim in the future.

Comment: I would be better if you let us know 1) what you think the verb is, and 2) Why you have a doubt

Comment: Laurel, it's verbatim.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Deep into distant woodlands winds a mazy way, reaching to overlapping*
> *spurs of mountains bathed in their hill-side blue*.

The subject is "a mazy way".

The sentence contains subject-dependent inversion: the basic non-inverted sentence would be

> *A mazy way winds deep into distant woodlands, reaching to overlapping*
> *spurs of mountains bathed in their hill-side blue*

In both constructions, the principal (main clause) verb is "winds".

Answer (score 0):

There are several verbs.

The main, finite verb is "[winds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/wind#:%7E:text=wind%20along/down/through%2C%20etc)"  (pronounced /waindz/)  it is the 3rd person singular form of "wind" meaning the "way" has lots of bends.  Don't confuse with the noun "wind"  meaning a movement of air.

Other verbs are "reaching" and "bathed".  These verbs are participles, and they form phrases that describe where the road goes and what the mountains look like.